# Converting a Ballerina record with an error field to json

Tags: json, ballerina

How can I convert the record given below to a `json` value?

```php
type PaymentEvent record {
    string orderId;
    string message;
    string occurredAt = time:utcToString(time:utcNow());
    anydata|error payload?;
};
```

Comment: I'm genuinely curious; what is the value of asking canned questions and having the same colleagues answer them? Is it to build a documentation system or? Why not just use the site to ask questions to which you don't know the answer. I've seen this quite a bit lately, and I just don't understand it. Again, not suggesting it isn't allowed or anything, just wondering what the goal is.

Comment: The intention here is to share the queries raised about Ballerina programming (mainly in the discord server) publicly, creating a resource that is accessible to the broader community. This practice is also in line with Stack Overflow's encouragement of such contributions. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`toJson()`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0/functions#toJson) langlib function to convert any `anydata` value to json.

But, that is not possible here since the payload field allows an error value, which does not belong to `json`. So you would have to explicitly map to `json` or  convert to some intermediate record without the error and then use `toJson()` (but that would add an additional conversion).

```php
import ballerina/time;

type PaymentEvent record {
    string orderId;
    string message;
    string occurredAt = time:utcToString(time:utcNow());
    anydata|error payload?;
};

function convert(PaymentEvent event) returns map<json> {
    map<json> eventJson = {
        orderId: event.orderId,
        message: event.message,
        occurredAt: event.occurredAt
    };

    if event.hasKey("payload") {
        anydata|error payload = event?.payload;

        if payload is error {
            // handle the scenario where the payload is an error
        } else {
            eventJson["payload"] = payload.toJson();
        }
    }

    return eventJson;
}
```